# Prove or disprove that $f_n(x)\gt -1/2$

Tags: inequality, graphing-functions

This post is sort of followup of
[Prove or disprove that the function is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4196614/prove-or-disprove-that-the-function-is-convex/),
a question coined up by [Erik Satie](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/698573/erik-satie).
Define $f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}x^{k^2}$ where $n\ge 1$ a natural number and $-1 \leq x \leq 1$.

From the picture below the fact seems evident but I have no idea how to prove it (otherwise). 
So, *prove or disprove* that $f_n(x) \gt -1/2$.

[image]

Some easy to prove facts about the function behaviour are noticed:
$$
\begin{cases}
f_n(-1) = 0 & ; & f_n'(-1) = \sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^{k-1} k^2 = -2n^2-n \lt 0 \\
f_n(0)=0 & ; & f_n'(0) = 1 \\
f_n(+1)=2n & ; & f_n'(+1) = \sum_{k=1}^{2n} k^2 = 2n(2n+1)(4n+1)/6
\end{cases}
$$
Numerically:

```
n =  1 ; minimum = -4.72466351692463E-0001 at x = -6.31262525050100E-0001
n =  2 ; minimum = -4.98653787376657E-0001 at x = -7.51503006012024E-0001
n =  3 ; minimum = -4.99936871867468E-0001 at x = -8.11623246492986E-0001
n =  4 ; minimum = -4.99997098383334E-0001 at x = -8.47695390781563E-0001
n =  5 ; minimum = -4.99999866659599E-0001 at x = -8.71743486973948E-0001
n =  6 ; minimum = -4.99999993940378E-0001 at x = -8.91783567134269E-0001
n =  7 ; minimum = -4.99999999732976E-0001 at x = -9.03807615230461E-0001
n =  8 ; minimum = -4.99999999987309E-0001 at x = -9.15831663326653E-0001
n =  9 ; minimum = -4.99999999999449E-0001 at x = -9.23847695390782E-0001
n = 10 ; minimum = -4.99999999999967E-0001 at x = -9.31863727454910E-0001
n = 11 ; minimum = -4.99999999999999E-0001 at x = -9.35871743486974E-0001
n = 12 ; minimum = -5.00000000000000E-0001 at x = -9.39879759519038E-0001
```

Comment: From the answer by River Li: If $0\le x \le 1$, we have $f_n(x) \ge 0$. If $-1 \lt x \lt 0$, we have $f_n(x) \gt f_{n + 1}(x)$ for all $n\ge 1$. I should have augmented my _easy to prove facts_ with these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $0 \le x \le 1$, we have $f_n(x) \ge 0$. True.

If $x = -1$, we have $f_n(-1) = 0$. True.

If $-1 < x < 0$, we have
$f_n(x) > f_{n + 1}(x)$ for all $n\ge 1$.
Also, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{k^2} = \frac{1}{2}\vartheta_3(0, x) - \frac{1}{2} > -\frac{1}{2}$
where $\vartheta_3(z, q) = 1 + 2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty q^{k^2}\cos (2k z)$ is the Jacobi theta function, and we have used
the property $\vartheta_3(0, q)= \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^{2n})(1+q^{2n-1})^2$.
Thus, $f_n(x) > -\frac12$. True.

We are done.

Comment: That is it. (I had just found https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1589581 and was about to assemble a similar answer :)

Comment: I wonder if the same method can be used to reduce https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4196614/42969 to the question whether $\vartheta_3(0, x)$ is convex.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, thanks for the link.

Comment: Indeed, the limit of my function graph for $n\to\infty$ is very similar to this [picture](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/JacobiThetaFunctions_1001.gif) of $\vartheta_3$ at Wolfram MathWorld.

Comment: And the formula $\vartheta_3(0, q)= \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^{2n})(1+q^{2n-1})^2$ is a special case of equation (92) at the same [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html) page for $z=0$. Right?
But I am _not done_ until I know how to _derive_ that equality $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n^2} = \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-x^{2n})(1+x^{2n-1})^2$ from first principles.

Comment: @HandeBruijn What is first principles here?

Comment: Sorry, after several attempts I still cannot understand why $1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty q^{n^2}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^{2n})(1+q^{2n-1})^2$, with $-1\lt q\lt 0$ real-valued, would be true.
That's the reason why I upvoted your answer as a whole but issued an unaccept for the last step.

Comment: @HandeBruijn There is a proof in Page 462, Whittaker, E. T. and Watson, G. N. A Course in Modern Analysis, 2nd Eds., 1915.

Comment: @RiverLi: Found it on the internet and going to absorb some of it. Thanks.